# Could not get complete URL

Tags: php, url

I am using this to get my current url.

```
https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]
```

But it is not returning character after #. I have my url like this

```
https://example.com/category/post/#loc
```

and with this code i am getting only

```
https://example.com/category/post/
```

How i can get a complete url?

Comment: The `#` part, the anchor, is not sent as part of the request and is invisible to the server, it's purely a client-side notation used for positioning the page or, recently, preserving client-side state.

Comment: As tadman said. You have to use Javascript on the requested page to find whatever is after the `#`, then either query for the correct content or redirect to another page.

Comment: Ok Thank you for your time. I am clear about it now.